# Не работает конструкция switch

Tags: javascript, switch, case

```
'use strict'

let message = document.querySelector('.message').value,
    result = document.querySelector('.result'),
    button = document.querySelector('.button');


button.onclick = () =>{
    switch (message.value) {
        case 'Привет Бот' && 'Привет':
            result.innerHTML = ('Привет Человек')
            break;
        case 'Пока Бот':
            result.innerHTML = ('Пока человек')
            break;
        case 'Как дела?':
            result.innerHTML = ('Хорошо!')
            break;
        default:
            result.innerHTML = ('Извните, я не понял ваш вопрос')
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Comment: Так `case 'Привет Бот' && 'Привет':` работать не будет

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, будет :) просто не совсем так, как ожидает автор

Answer (score 2):

Вы уже в строчке `let message = document.querySelector('.message').value` взяли текст у элемента, поэтому здесь `message.value` происходит ошибка. Должно быть просто `switch (message) {`

Comment: _взяли текст у элемента, поэтому здесь message.value происходит ошибка_ - ну не, просто проверяется значение `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Как вам описали в  комментарии  и ответе -  вы два раза берете текст у элемента. И конструкция к тому же с  &&  не будет работать. я немого переработал алгоритм, добавил обработку случаев с  введением вариантов текста.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const message = input.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    switch (true) {
        case message.includes('Привет'.toLowerCase()):
            result.textContent = 'Привет Человек';
            break;
        case message.includes('Пока'.toLowerCase()):
            result.textContent = 'Пока человек';
            break;
        case message.includes('Как дела'.toLowerCase()):
            result.textContent = 'Хорошо!';
            break;
        default:
            result.textContent = 'Извните, я не понял ваш вопрос';
            break;
    }
});
```

```html
<input class = 'input'/>
<button class= "button">send</button>
<div class= 'result'></div>
```